# Problem in downgrading from Vista to WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, hp-pavilion, downgrade

I have an HP laptop (HP Pavilion DV 2000) with MS Vista 64 bit. I want to downgrade to Windows XP. I have a valid 32 bit Windows XP bootable CD. When I try to insert it and format the system, it runs fine uptil a stage then suddenly I get the message

> Your computer is being shut down to prevent damage to Windows.

And the laptop shuts down.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Please edit your original post to include the exact model number of your HP...http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/findModel?lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us

Comment: gave up and installed Win7 instead. works perfectly now. Much better than VISTA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it was a drivers issue with the hard disk. I tried a number of options but nothing worked. So in the end I gave up and installed Win7. Install was painless and laptop works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

During the point at which XP setup prompts you to select a partition to install windows to, opt to delete the partition, recreate it, and format it.

Comment: hi. it does not reach that stage. this error occurs while windows setup is loading driver files etc onto the memory

Answer (score 0):

You can also download [Gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) and burn it to a disk and use it to create a new partition for Vista. It is Linux based and runs fast. After you create your partition, restart the laptop with your WinXP disk and see if this works for you.